# Library app Vs Standalone iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

I am building a native iPhone application wherein this application will act as a standalone app on one device and act as a library on other device. Can you please guide me how should I design the app. Should the same method "applicationDidFinishedLaunching" be called in both the cases and just in the basis of some parameters I will be distinguishing from where the call was made. This is because, in both the cases, I have some different screen flows.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by standalone vs library app. Just remember that only one app can be actively running at a time.

Comment: Yes. That is true.     Here is what I meant by standalone and lib....     @Standalone -- My app will be launched by tapping on the application icon.             @Lib -- My app will be called by tapping on a button on some other application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library code has to be compiled into the running app to be used.  No other app can access your code, as all apps are sandboxed and prohibited from accessing each other's directories, and thus any code contained in such.  If someone taps on another icon, it will be as if your library code does not exist to that app.

Another app can start your app by using a registered launch URL, but that will just result in your app being brought to the foreground.  The other app will be put into the background or terminated.

Comment: Agreed. My plan is to install app differently on different devices. So for one type of devices it will be installed as a lib and for other type of devices it will be a stand alone app. But I am creating one application. So, wanted to know is there code related changes I need to handle to support the above said app behavior. Please suggest.